# Parse HTML as a plain text via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I am making some ajax request that returns the whole HTML page as the response. I need to grab some data from that page, in particular, `value` of specific `<input>`.

What is the best way to do that?

My ideas:

- Find where the `<body>` tag ends and `</body>` starts, grab all stuff inside to string, and put via `innerHTML` to some container.
- Self-made parser: find the character position of the id I need, convert response string to an array, set position of reading equals position of id character, shift to where `"` character starts, read to buffer until new `"` come.

It would be perfect if there is a framework that uses classic DOM syntax to do that, like:

```
htmlString.getElementById("someid").value
```

Comment: _"What is the best way..."_ ask for a (most likely) opinion-based answer which is off-topic for SO. _"It would be perfect if there is a framework..."_ asks for an external resource which is also off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Andreas the best way (obviously) means the fastest, the easiest to use. It is not subjective, because we can count how many steps one should do, how much time it cost to run it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pretty elegant solution is to use DOMParser.

```
const parser = new DOMParser()
const virtualDoc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')
```

Then, treat `virtualDoc` like you'd treat any DOM-element,

```
virtualDoc.getElementById('someid').value
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: `virtualDom` should be `virtualDoc`.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t know how good is it, but just passing the whole response with `<html>` and others tags to some container works. Then, one needs just to call

```
document.getElementById("needid").value
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, then please make it a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)